# Get null Object even data exist in database in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using entity framework approch code first in asp.net mvc project , 
when I want the list of chargeClienteleDetails in its controller , it return data but If I use the same code in another controller , it return null ,!

this is chargeClienteleDetails's defenition :

```
public class ChargeClienteleDetails
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string EmailCC { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10)]
    public string NumClient { get; set; }
}
```

ChargeClienteleDetailsController's action :

```
private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext()
// GET: ChargeClienteleDetails
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.CCDetails.ToList());// return Data 
}
```

ChargeClienteleController  (the another controller ) :

```
private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext()
public ActionResult Index()
{    
    var c2 = db.CCDetails.ToList();   // return null   
    return View(c2); 
}
```

Comment: are you sure `db` and `context` refer to the same data source?

Comment: Yes  , they refer to the same data source :          private ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();                       private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

Comment: Have you tested that? It seems that they might be referring to a different database context

Comment: yes I tested them and I get the same problem

Comment: So you are saying `db.CCDetails` itself is returning null (`ToList()` itself never will)? Are you doing some custom code in `ApplicationDbContext` to return `CCDetails`? otherwise I can't see how this is possible.

Comment: @Sarra can you please show us your ApplicationDbContext class

Comment: Thanks for all of you for replying me  , It works fine and return data  , without changing anything